# How much weight can studs hold for several rows of shelves?

Tags: drywall, shelving

I am planning on fitting 6 shelves one above the other to a plasterboard wall. I've identified where two studs are and plan to use two j brackets for fitting each shelf.

I can't find much advice online about the maximum load for fitting multiple sets of shelves to a pair of studs. Should I be worried about loads?

The shelves are only 90x22cm (width x length), the maximum load on each shelf will probably be about 20kg if it's filled with heavy books, so maybe 120 kg total load in the worst case.

Comment: Usually it is the weight limit of the shelves and brackets that is the worry.  If the shelves and brackets can hold the weight and you use the proper size of screws into the studs, you will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it. That's similar to a kitchen cabinet full of dishes. Perfectly normal.